# Proof by induction that $3^{2n}-1$ is divisible by 8.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction, divisibility

## Proof by induction

Let the property $P(n)$ be the sentence
$$
3^{2n}-1 \text{ is divisible by 8} 
$$

### Base case:

Let $n = 0$ and we have
$$
3^{2 \cdot 0} - 1 = 3^0 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0 
$$
and $0$ is divisible by $8$ because $0 = 8 \cdot 0$. Hence $P(0)$ is true.

### Induction step:

Let $k$ be any integer where $k \geq 0$ and suppose $P(k)$. That is, suppose $3^{2k}-1$ is divisible by $8$. We need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true. That is, we need to show that
$3^{2(k + 1)}-1$ is divisible by $8$.

Now,
\begin{align}
3^{2(k + 1)}-1
&= 9 \cdot 3^{2k}-1\\
&= (8 + 1) \cdot 3^{2k}-1\\
&= 8 \cdot 3^{2k} + 3^{2k}-1\\
&= 8 \cdot 3^{2k} + 8r \tag{ *** }\\
&= 8(3^{2k} + r)
\end{align}

But $3^{2k} + r$ is an integer since $3^{2k}$ and $r$ are integers. Hence by the definition of divisibility $3^{2(k + 1)}-1$ is divisible by $8$.

*** Substituting for $8r$ because $3^{2k}-1$ is divisible by $8$ by the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: Where is your doubt? From the `solution-verification` tag [info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info): *For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.*

Comment: And, of course, for any odd integer $m$ we have $m^{2n}-1=(m^n)^2-1=(m^n-1)(m^n+1)$ is divisible by 8 since those are two consecutive even numbers so one of them is also divisible by 4. This is also divisible by $m-1$ so more may be true.

Comment: The *only* thing I'd do to this is I would explain what $r$ is and where it came from.  That is when you say "Suppose $3^{2k} -1$ is divisible by $8$" I'd add.  "That means there exists an integer $r$ so that $3^{2k} - 1 = 8r$".  If we jump for $8\cdot 3^{2k} +3^{2k} -1 = 8\cdot 3^{2k} + 8r$ there is no explanation what $r$ is or any reason why $3^{2k}-1=8r$.  (What if $3^{2k}-1 = 8z$ but $z\ne r$?  What if $r$ were the square root of $\pi$?  What if $r = 0$ and that just plain dangedy was not true at all?)